# Configurar o xamarin

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

Estou aprendendo xamarin e desenvolvimento para mobile. Tenho visto vário exemplos de como montar uma pequena aplicação e vejo que praticamente todos começam assim: Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) ou em português. Acontece, que quando eu crio uma nova aplicação, não tenho essa opção. Já atualizei o xamarin em minha máquina e nada. Quando eu digito xamarin no campo para pesquisa, me mostra várias outras opções, mas menos essa. Quando me aperece um Blank App é para Android apenas. Como configurar ou há outras opções para eu fazer que seja equivalente a essa, ou seja, desenvolver para as três plataformas praticamente ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Qual VisualStudio você está usando?

Comment: No VisualStudio 2017 essas opções mudaram. Vou colocar uma resposta que pode te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Visual Studio 2017 as opções para criação de um projeto mudaram um pouco. Se não está usando o VS2017 recomendo que faça o download do mesmo e utilize-o. Já que está começando, é melhor começar da forma certa.

Download do Visual Studio 2017: [Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/)

Dentro do Visual Studio, clique em File/New/Project ou Arquivo/Novo/Projeto. A seguinte tela irá aparecer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo o que percebi, você quer desenvolver para as 3 plataformas ao mesmo tempo. A forma mais simples e fácil (pelo menos pra mim) é através do Xamarin.Forms, onde você cria o layout (XAML) e o código (C#) do seu aplicativo apenas uma vez e o Visual Studio se encarrega de compilar e gerar código nativo para as 3 palataformas: Android, iOS e UWP.

Seguindo essa ideia, selecione Visual C#/Cross-Platform no menu lateral esquerdo. Após, marque a opção Cross Platform App (Xamarin) do lado direito do menu e por fim, coloque um nome para o seu projeto na parte inferior da janela. Feito isso, clique em OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após isso, a seguinte tela será aberta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que agora você tem a opção de selecionar o BlankApp que antes não via. Aqui então, selecione BlankApp, logo abaixo selecione Xamarin.Forms e ao lado escolha a estratégia de compartilhamento de código. Por fim, clique em OK e seu projeto será criado.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas usando o VS2015. Eu tenho sim o 2017, acho que vou preferir usá-lo para esses projetos.

Comment: Eu também usava o 2015, mas quando vi o evento de lançamento do 2017, troquei imediatamente. Ele é muito melhor otimizado para desenvolvimento mobile.

Comment: existe algum tipo de VM para MAC rodando no windows para testar os Apps IOS?

Comment: você precisa de pelo menos um computador MAC físico para funcionar

Comment: O Xamarin Test Cloud, eu consigo usar o MAC nessa plataforma?

Comment: Não sei ao certo, pois nunca usei. Mas creio que sim.